# Hibernate: как сделать частичную загрузку класса?

Tags: jpa, hibernate, java

Господа, просветите, пожалуйста, по таким вопросам:

1. У меня есть сущность, которая содержит наборы других сущностей. То есть имеет место One-To-Many mapping. Однако в ряде случаев мне хотелось бы загружать из базы эти вложенные сущности, отобранные по некоторым критериям. К примеру: *Менеджер* содержит *Проекты*. Хочу показать не все проекты менеджера, а только зарубежные. Или отобрать всех менеджеров, у которых есть активный проект. И т.д.
    Как это лучше организовать?
2. Есть ли принципиальная разница между использованием Criteria и HQL? Что для чего лучше?
3. Есть такая штука как lazy loading. Если я правильно понимаю, она вместо того чтобы считывать вложенную сущность, создает на лету вместо нее объект некоего класса, который называется proxy и при обращении к его методам идет обращение к базе. 
   Так вот, в ряде случаев я **знаю точно**, что мне не понадобятся эти вложенные объекты вообще. То есть я хочу загрузить всех *Менеджеров*, не обращая внимания на их *Проекты* вообще, без данных о *Проектах*. Могу ли я как-то сказать Hibernate об этом и тем самым увеличить скорость его работы за счет избежания join'a?  Или если стоит lazy loading, то это не имеет смысла?
    
   Поясню, что это нужно не всегда, а лишь для некоторых запросов к базе. То есть если бы я писал на SQL, я бы сделал 2 запроса один с join, другой без. А как этот "без" сделать в Hibernate? Не писать же вторую сущность без соотв. коллекции.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- **(1)** В случае грамотно настроенного маппинга у вас не должно возникнуть проблем в составлении грамотного запроса к базе, чтобы показать, например, только зарубежные проекты. В случае C# и NHibernate, например, такой запрос можно было бы реализовать как `entities.Select(e => e.Projects).Where(project => project.Country != "RU)`. *Можете оформить схожий запрос в Java любым удобным способом.*
- **(2)** Давний спор, лично я полностью солидарен с принятым ответом [**здесь.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197474/hibernate-criteria-vs-hql) Основной аргумент - удобочитаемость HQL и "удобоизменяемость" Criteria.
- **(3)** Не стоит измерять производительность запросов join'ами, тем более, сначала напишите, а **только потом** оптимизируйте. В вашем случае - это канонический пример lazy-loading'а, когда у каждого объекта внутри него существует коллекция других объектов, *которые не являются релевантными для текущего запроса.*

---

**Замечания к (3):**

Если в своем маппинге вы включите lazy-fetching для этой коллекции, то все обращений будут заменены на "ленивые" прокси, выполняющие подгрузку по мере необходимости. **Таким образом, запрос, не затрагивающий каких-либо членов или параметры коллекции, не вызовет ее подгрузку.**

Здесь существует еще один подводный камень - если ваша коллекция "ленивая", то все ее элементы при последовательной работе с ними будут подгружаться по очереди. Если хочется этого избежать и *загрузить все за один запрос к базе*, то возможно, например, схитрить и совершить вызов метода типа `instance.childrenCollection.getSize()`, который и вызовет полную прогрузку всех элементов.

Comment: Можно добавить, что `lazy-fetching` можно переопределить на этапе составления запроса (используя Criteria или HQL).
Также "хитрое" использование `size()` можно заменить на более говорящее `Hibernate.initialize()`

Comment: Спасибо! Вот еще: известно что можно задавать fetching strategy в мэппингах или в Criteria. А в HQL это можно сделать? Просто похоже что только через Criteria я могу создать один метод ДАО который будет выдавать сущности с подгруженными объектами или нет. А через HQL это не задашь.

Comment: В HQL есть ключевое слово <a href="http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins">fetch</a> - позволяет указать принудительную подгрузку в одном селекте.

Comment: Ясно. Осталась одна деталь непонятная: по самому первому вопросу. Мне кажется, ответ Котика просто выдаст все Проекты, у которых поле страна не `RU`. Мне же надо подгрузить в сущность Менеджер соотв. ему Проекты, но не все, а только "не RU". То есть Менеджер уже имеет `OneToMany mapping` на аннотациях, но в результате использования аннотаций должны подгрузиться не все Проекты, а лишь те что "страна не RU". Это на HQL через `join: select from Manager m join m.Projects p where p.country!="RU"`?

Answer (score 0):

Для решения первого вопроса можно использовать аннотацию @org.hibernate.annotations.Where(clause = "country != 'RU'")

Ее надо написать там, где аннотация OneToMany.

Текст присваемый clause будет добавлен в where sql (не HQL!) и его надо писать используя названия имен таблиц БД.

Такую аннотацию можно написать только одну для одного entity класса.

Если надо много вариантов (русские, нерусские и т. д.). то наверное надо использовать наследование классов, используя для каждого класса свой шаблон для where. 
Но я не пробовал использовать наследование.